# Python Function: Given Scrabble Tile, What is the value?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a simple function that given a letter, you are returned the value of the scrabble tile. Here is what I have:

```
def letterPoint(letter):


    letter = letter.upper()

    lettersWorthOne =(['A','E','I','N','O','R','S','T'])
    lettersWorthTwo = (['D','G'])
    lettersWorthThree = (['B','C','M','P'])
    lettersWorthFour = (['F','H','U','V','W','Y'])
    lettersWorthFive = (['K'])
    lettersWorthEight = (['J','X'])
    lettersWorthTen = (['Q','Z'])

    if letterWorthOne:
        print '1'

    if letterWorthTwo:
        print '2'

    if letterWorthThree:
        print '3'

    if letterWorthFour:
        print '4'

    if letterWorthFive:
        print '5'

    if letterWorthEight:
        print '8'

    if letterWorthTen:
        print '10'
```

Comment: Isn't that cheating in Scrabble?

Comment: thanks. appreciate the input.

Comment: The parentheses around your lists are doing nothing and are confusing.  You should remove them and only use parentheses around value declarations like that if you are trying to create a tuple with more than one element.  If you meant to create a tuple from each list, you could do `tuple(["a","b","c"])`. However, in that case you don't really need the list at all and could have done `("a","b","c")`, but only if you have more than one element inside the tuple, otherwise you do need to convert from a list (for 1 or 0 elements)

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a way I can use the dict as a function call, like my function posted, def letterValue(letter):

Comment: *"use the dict as a function call"* wouldn't make sense even if you *actually had a `dict` anywhere*.

Comment: was talking about the edits posted below.

Comment: ...and by *"edits"* you mean *answers*? Please **fix your question** - what output do you get, for what inputs, and what did you expect instead? Your current code makes no sense; `if <non-empty list>:` will *always* be `True`, and you are using `if` instead of `elif`, so it just `print`s everything in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary. Rather than
`lettersWorthTwo = (['D','G'])`, etc.

You would have a data structure along the lines of:

`letterValues = {'D':2, 'G':2, ... }`

Then a lookup for value is simply:
`letterValues['D'] # returns 2 for the value of the tile`

Comment: It would have been nice if you explained why his original solution, while not optimal, wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

To point out why your code doesn't work, because you're not comparing your letter to the list.

```
#Change from this:
    if letterWorthOne:
        print '1'
#to this, should work
    if letter in letterWorthOne:
        print '1'
.....
```

Use a python **dictionary** is the way to go.

Further to the solution someone has already posted. You can also construct a more content dictionary like this:

```
Letters = {
'a': { 'quantity' : 9, 'value': 1},
'b': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 3},
'c': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 3},
'd': { 'quantity' : 4, 'value': 2},
'e': { 'quantity' : 12, 'value': 1},
'f': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 4},
'g': { 'quantity' : 3, 'value': 2},
'h': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 4},
'i': { 'quantity' : 9, 'value': 1},
'j': { 'quantity' : 1, 'value': 8},
'k': { 'quantity' : 1, 'value': 5},
'l': { 'quantity' : 4, 'value': 1},
'm': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 3},
'n': { 'quantity' : 6, 'value': 1},
'o': { 'quantity' : 8, 'value': 1},
'p': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 3},
'q': { 'quantity' : 1, 'value': 10},
'r': { 'quantity' : 6, 'value': 1},
's': { 'quantity' : 4, 'value': 1},
't': { 'quantity' : 6, 'value': 1},
'u': { 'quantity' : 4, 'value': 1},
'v': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 4},
'w': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 4},
'x': { 'quantity' : 1, 'value': 8},
'y': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 4},
'z': { 'quantity' : 1, 'value': 10},
'*': { 'quantity' : 2, 'value': 0}

}

# to get to it's "content", like this:
Letters['a']
{'quantity': 9, 'value': 1}

# you can then get its 'value' or 'quantity' in a tile bag
Letters['a']['value']
1


# if you MUST use a function, do this with above dictionary, although it's quite pointless
def letter_point(letter):
    return Letters[letter.upper()]['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

In `letterPoint()`, `letterWorthOne` and `lettersWorthOne` are separate variables.  Each `lettersWorth*` variable holds a list, and you appear to want `letterWorthOne` to contain a boolean value (`True` or `False`) specifying whether or not `letter` is in the `lettersWorthOne` list.  To determine whether a value is in a collection, use operator `in`.

```
def letterPoint(letter):
    letter = letter.upper()

    lettersWorthOne =(['A','E','I','N','O','R','S','T'])
    lettersWorthTwo = (['D','G'])

    letterWorthOne = letter in lettersWorthOne
    if letterWorthOne:
        print '1'

    letterWorthTwo = letter in lettersWorthTwo
    if letterWorthTwo:
        print '2'

    # rest of values omitted for brevity

print 'E worth'
letterPoint('E')
print 'D worth'
letterPoint('D')
```

This program produces the following output:

```
E worth
1
D worth
2
```

This explains why your existing function doesn't work.  But in the long run, I'd recommend using a dictionary to hold the value and quantity of each letter, and store the values as numbers instead of strings so that you can add the values of all letters in a word.

Answer (score 0):

To use the code you began with, you could consider changing the lines to:

```
if letter in lettersWorthOne print 1
...
```

This is because the data structure you're using is a `list` (it is surrounded by `[]` brackets). The way to use these lists in your function is to see `if` they contain the letter `in` the list using the code:

```
if <variable> in <list> print <value>
```

The `()` brackets aren't doing anything, as mentioned in another answer so you can get rid of them.

This is just to explain to you why you don't see any result in the function you've written. The other answers which suggest using a `dict` (dictionary) are a better approach in practice.